# Why do I get the error, "pygame.error: Couldn't read first 12 bytes of audio data" when I drop a mp3 file on to the window?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I have been creating a Music Player, and I'm in the process of it. I'm a beginner at pygame. I keep getting the error: "pygame.error: Couldn't read first 12 bytes of audio data." when I drop an mp3 file onto my window. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import os

# Created this function because it seems like rect collidepoint isn't working.

def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    # create a list of file and sub directories
    # names in the given directory
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    # Iterate over all the entries
    for entry in listOfFile:
        # Create full path
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        # If entry is a directory then get the list of files in this directory
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)

    return allFiles



pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

background = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(350, 575))
back_color = (0, 175, 175)
background.fill(back_color)


while True:
    pygame.display.set_caption("Music Player " + str(pygame.mouse.get_pos()))  # Taking the pos for a good idea where to place sprites.
    ev = pygame.event.get()
    background.fill(back_color)
    for event in ev:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.DROPFILE:
            if os.path.isdir(event.file):
                queue = getListOfFiles(event.file)
            if os.path.isfile(event.file):
                queue = event.file
            if not pygame.mixer.get_busy():
                for x in queue:
                    pygame.mixer.music.load(x)
                    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)
                    if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
                        pygame.mixer.music.play()
            print(queue)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

EDIT: Someone, please explain why this error is happening.

This is the complete error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daksh/Desktop/Personal/IDLE Script and Data/PycharmProjects/AdvancedPrograms/Music Player.py", line 105, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load(x)
pygame.error: Couldn't read first 12 bytes of audio data
```

The file I dropped on my pygame window was a regular mp3 file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It's fine if you write "some unnecessary code that is not being used", but you should be able to identify the part of your program that is *relevant to the problem*, and create a code sample that is *complete*, but still *focused on the problem*. We don't need something that handles `MOUSEBUTTONUP` or does collision detection.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*. We are not interested in your level of experience, your assessment of the state of the project, etc. We *are* interested in a *clear, focused* question. "I hope someone can help me" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236); "explain why this error is happening is closer, but we need more context - which includes a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message.

Comment: Okay, I have done the necessary edits. @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Just forgot to make the variable "queue" a list because it is being iterated.
Solved code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import os

# Created this function because it seems like rect collidepoint isn't working.

def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    # create a list of file and sub directories
    # names in the given directory
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    # Iterate over all the entries
    for entry in listOfFile:
        # Create full path
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        # If entry is a directory then get the list of files in this directory
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)

    return allFiles



pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

background = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(350, 575))
back_color = (0, 175, 175)
background.fill(back_color)


while True:
    pygame.display.set_caption("Music Player " + str(pygame.mouse.get_pos()))  # Taking the pos for a good idea where to place sprites.
    ev = pygame.event.get()
    background.fill(back_color)
    for event in ev:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.DROPFILE:
            if os.path.isdir(event.file):
                queue = getListOfFiles(event.file)
            if os.path.isfile(event.file):
                queue = [event.file] # Changed HERE (put square brackets around queue)
            if not pygame.mixer.get_busy():
                for x in queue:
                    pygame.mixer.music.load(x)
                    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)
                    if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
                        pygame.mixer.music.play()
            print(queue)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pygame, but you should probably test it with a folder as well. That `for x in queue:` loop looks as if it will only try *once, right now* to play all the files; since it will be "busy" after playing the first one in the folder, I expect the others not to get played at all.

Comment: Actually, that is true. So later I added a while loop that doesn't end until the song is finished.